# How can I maintain the scroll position of a custom select box in React?

Tags: reactjs, select

I customized and created a select box UI. Whenever I open a new select box, I want to focus scrolling on the selected item.

My Selectbox list is processing overflow-y scrolling.

What should I do?

```
const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState<string>('')
const [isOpenOption, setIsOpenOption] = useState<boolean>(false)

const handleToggle = useCallback((e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    setIsOpenOption(prev => !prev)
  }, [])

const handleSelect = useCallback(
    (e, option: string) => {
      e.preventDefault()
      if (option !== selectedOption) {
        setSelectedOption(option)
      }
      setIsOpenOption(false)
    },
    [selectedOption, onChange],
  )
 
<div className={'select'}>
  <ul className={cx('list')} role="listbox">
    {options.map((option, index) => (
      <li key={`${index}`} className={'item'}>
        <a
          role="option"
          className={'option'}
          aria-selected={option === selectedOption}
          onClick={event => handleSelect(event, option)}>
            {option}
        </a>
      </li>
     ))}
  </ul>
</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wvLH.png)